# Group by two different type in one column and get the sum of them

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-server-2008-r2

Here I have a List like this :

```
GroupList = value.GroupBy(p => new { p.DraftStateId, p.DraftTypeId, p.SrcTeamId, p.PartsId, p.PartsType }).ToList();
```

The `DraftStateId` Column have 4 different types.

```
     DraftStateId        Count
         type1             5
         type2             8
         type3             6
         type4             7
```

Now how can I sum the count of `type1` And `type2` and show them as `type1`?

Comment: Is this an in memory list, or are you referring to an EF/Linq2Sql query?

Comment: you mean GroupList? It's a **List<T>** that **T** is a View from my tables.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring to a database query, you would first need to execute the query, then perform the custom grouping in memory.

```
var grouping = value
      .GroupBy(p => new { p.DraftStateId, p.DraftTypeId, p.SrcTeamId, p.PartsId, p.PartsType })
      .ToList()
      .GroupBy(p => p.DraftStateId)
      .GroupBy(p => {
        if (p.Key == "type1" || p.Key == "type2")
            return "type1";
        return p.Key;
      })
      .Select(p => new { DraftStateId = p.Key, Count = p.Sum(x => x.Count()) });
```

Comment: I need to return all the columns values, and only want to sum the count of `type1` And `type2` in DraftStateId column.